# C++ Problem: Class Promotion using derived class

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism, class-design

I have a class for Float32 that is derived from Float32_base

```
    class Float32_base {
        public:
        // Constructors
        Float32_base(float x) : value(x) {};
        Float32_base(void) : value(0) {};
        operator float32(void) {return value;};
        Float32_base operator =(float x) {value = x; return *this;};
        Float32_base operator +(float x) const { return value + x;};

    protected:
        float value;

    }

    class Float32 : public Float32_base {
        public:
        float Tad() {
            return value + .01;
        }
    }

    int main() {
        Float32 x, y, z;
        x = 1; y = 2;

    // WILL NOT COMPILE!
        z = (x + y).Tad(); 

    // COMPILES OK
        z = ((Float32)(x + y)).Tad(); 
    }
```

The issue is that the + operator returns a Float32_base and Tad() is not in that class. But 'x' and 'y' are Float32's.

Is there a way that I can get the code in the first line to compile without having to resort to a typecast like I did on the next line?

Comment: `Tad()` is private in the `Float32` class. Are you missing a `public` somewhere? And what's the point of separate `Float32` and `Float32_base` classes? It seems to me that you can put everything in a single `Float32` class and have it work the exact same way.

Comment: In this case, you could simply override `operator+` in `Float32`.  Presumably your real situation is more complicated than this?

Comment: The class "Float32" is intended to be platform specific. Tad() is different on different platforms. I wanted to use a base class "Float32_base" for all the general stuff that floats can do, but put platform specific code in "Float32".

Comment: Does your code even work? Your `operator+` has signature `Float32_base(float)`, so how can you add `x + y`? There's no cast operator for `float`?! Also, what is `float32`?

Comment: Sorry if the code is wrong or incomplete in this post. It does work, but too much to show here.

Comment: get rid of the base class, I don't see why would you need it, and make `operator+` a friend.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) if you only need one-level deep inheritance:

```
template <typename T>
struct A
{
  T
  operator+ (const A&)
  { return T (); }
};

struct B : A <B>
{
  void
  lol ()
  { }
};

int
main ()
{
  B a, b;
  (a + b).lol ();
}
```

Comment: Looks like this was the magic sauce I was looking for! I created a template FloatT_base<typename T, typename Tflt,typename Tint> and then used it as the base class: Class Float32_T: FloatT_base<Float32_T, float, int> and Voilà!

Comment: @MichaelFitzpatrick I'd suggest you to flag it as accepted then.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the operator+ method since your return type for operator+ is defined as Float32_base.  You can do this through covariance and make the method virtual.  Then override the method in your subclass (you could probably just call the method in the superclass).

You could also do this through Templates, but if you're not familiar with Templates I wouldn't suggest digging into it.  Essentially you would define the virtual function the way you already did but instead of returning Float32_base, you would return your template type.  (as long as your template type is a subclass then C++ should be good with contravariance).  Your subclass would extend the baseclass with a template of the subclass.

Comment: I added the code: "Float32 operator +(float32 x) const { return Float32_base::operator+(x);};" to Float32{} and that works. It is just that that defeats the purpose. If I have to do that for every method I may as well not have a base class.

Answer (score 0):

You can template the `FLoat32_base` class on the result type of operations.

Or put everything into a single class (probably best), delegating the few platform-specific operations to platform specific functions.

Cheers & hth.,